# Google Analytics - Doing a simple goal report

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

In the main report interface of Google Analytics under **Goals > Overview** it has a display of the goal name and the amount of completions for each goal.

What I want to do is replicate this in a custom report but I am having issues on how accomplish this. I have Goal Completions as a metric but it forces you to have a Dimension Drilldown and I can't see anything called Goal Name. Is there any way to replicate this very basic report?

Comment: This would be off topic as if related to reporting and not programming. Please post to Webmasters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension set in custom reports will always give a drill down, thus by using something broad like year, you can see all your data in one row. If I wanted to use custom reports to show a overview of goals, I would do this...

[Custom Report Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4Sn9.png)

[Custom Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j79hu.png)

Answer (score 1):

Goal Name would appear on metrics and google custom reports only show metrics to dimensions in report.

You can use any of below option for Dimensions

[image]

then you can select any of conversation rate of your goal from below metrics

[image]